# Display offline ArcGIS Esri map using Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, arcgis-js-api, esri-leaflet

I need to display ArcGIS ESRI map hosted in intranet environment.
I was following [this](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/showing-a-basemap.html) example and it works fine when system is connected to internet.

As our Map Server is hosted in intranet environment so I cannot use above example.
I have further investigated [ESRI leaflet](https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@3.0.2/dist/esri-leaflet.js) and found out that its making calls to online **arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer** for loading map tiles.  I replaced this URL with our Map server URL
**https://{our domain}/intsrv/rest/services/Cache/StreetsNightBlue/MapServer** but still tiles are not loaded.

**I have added all required CSS and JS files offline in my project already.**

```
 mapObject = L.map('mapDiv').setView([defaultLat, defaultLong], defaultZoom);
    L.esri.basemapLayer('Gray').addTo(mapObject);
    L.esri.Cluster.featureLayer({
        url: 'https://{our domain}/intsrv/rest/services/Cache/StreetsNightBlue/MapServer/0'
    }).addTo(mapObject);
```

When I run program, in console it giving tile not found error.

[image]

**Update:** Tiles appearing now but far away from marker cluster

[image]

Kindly help to fix this issue.

Comment: *which* tile is not found?  When using `L.esri.basemap`, you're requesting tiles from esri's gray basemap, which requires an internet connection.  Are those the tiles not being found?  Or is it your Cluster tiles that are not being found?

Comment: I am new to Leaflet esri and did not know that I am requesting tiles through internet. 
I need tiles to be loaded from my offline server, not from internet.
Map server is hosted at: https://{our domain}/intsrv/rest/services/Cache/StreetsNightBlue/MapServer

Comment: Yes hidden in the internals of `L.esri.basemap`, you are requesting their basemap tiles.  If you want those specific tiles for your basemap, you'll have to serve them yourself.  You didn't answer *which* tiles are not being found.

Comment: We already have setup offline server to serve tiles in intranet environment and tiles are loaded properly when I use ArcGis js api. I want to use ESRI leaflet JS to load tiles instead of ArcGIS API because I need to add other functionalities of leaflet later on. Hope it answers your question. Furthermore could you suggest piece of code which I need to put to load tiles from offline server.

Comment: I have added screenshot from browser console window.

Comment: It seems like your featurelayer is being treated as a tilelayer...are you sure the arcgis server where its hosted is treating it like a point feature layer, not a tile layer?

Comment: Quick update: I am able to load tiles from offline server to map surface. 
Now the problem is, it appears below marker cluster layer. I want marker clusters layer to appear at top of these tiles.

I have updated post with screenshot.

Comment: ArcGIS server is treating is like tile layer, thats why I am able to get is displayed but problem is its not displaying correctly with expected coordinate and zoom level.

Comment: Unfortunately without a reproducible example, its going to be hard to help debug.

Comment: I understand. Our map environment is restricted so can't give access in order for you to test. Anyhow could you recommend here a link of program which can help me in displaying marker clusters on ArcGis ESRI offline map tiles using Leaflet plugin.
I tried finding relevant example but failed.

Comment: Hi Bilal, I also recommend you to look for help using the [esri-leaflet issues](https://github.com/esri/esri-leaflet/issues).  In my case, like Seth, I can't do much without access.

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/3541972/hhkaos , are there instructions on how to work with esri-leaflet in offline mode? With a locally installed server?